# WHERE sessionId = session OR IF NOT MATCHING WHERE this is this. MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im sorry for the bad title.

im trying to create a script that would log users view on my website per session.

but I want to log bots that dont use cookie's once and not multiple time since they will have a diferent session id,

My current Code is

```
$getRecords = $this->dbCon->prepare("SELECT id FROM vis_records WHERE `time` >= :timeFrom AND sessionId = :sessionId OR ip = :ip");
$getRecords -> bindValue(':timeFrom',time()-(60*30)); // Only Search Records from the last 30 min
$getRecords -> bindValue(':sessionId',self::getSessionId());
$getRecords -> bindValue(':ip',self::getCurIp());
```

but the thing with that code is,.

If mysql find a matching sessionId OR ip it will give me a matching row.

What I want to do is 
If mysql find a sessionid that is matching then return me that row If Mysql can't find a matching sessionId THEN try to find a matching ip..

Is that possible directly in a mysql query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM vis_records WHERE `time` >= :timeFrom AND 
sessionId = :sessionId 
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM vis_records WHERE `time` >= :timeFrom AND 
ip = :ip AND
NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT id FROM vis_records WHERE `time` >= :timeFrom AND 
sessionId = :sessionId)
```

Comment: Cool Thanks I justread about union and i think that i what i need,  Let me test that and if it is it. il mark your awnser as apcepted.   Thanks!

Comment: Actuly i can't even run the sql :S i get the following msg `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM vis_records WHERE `time` >= 1391702868 AND se' at line 6`    Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding, you just need to couple the 'and' conditions together with parenthesis like so:

```
"SELECT id FROM vis_records WHERE (`time` >= :timeFrom AND sessionId = :sessionId) OR ip = :ip"
```